# Send commands in virtual environment of python in windows

Tags: batch-file, command

I am trying to set variables and then run a python program after activating the virtual environment. But only the first command below runs.

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Venv\Scripts\activate.bat" && set http_proxy=<proxyserver1>:80 && set https_proxy=<proxyserver12>:80 && py start.py
```

So basically I want the following commands to work in succession
activate the virtual environment - Works
Set the 2 proxy variables - Doesnt work
Run the start python program - Doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several examples of this already on the site.  A quick search would have shown you how to do this.

```
CALL "C:\Venv\Scripts\activate.bat"
set "http_proxy=<proxyserver1>:80"
set "https_proxy=<proxyserver12>:80"
py start.py
```